# What `dependent induction` tactic does in Coq and how to use it

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, induction

Can you please provide me with high-level explanation on which usecases `dependent induction` / `dependent destruct` tactics have, and how they work (I would be grateful for explanation high-level enough for a beginner to understand).

Everything I found on it so far is extremely overcomplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we know inductive data types are often indexed by indices, a basic example that you may have seen is the vector that is indexed by a Type and its size.

Given an example of a vector `t A (S n)`, since we know that the vector has a size higher than 0, we know there is a value of type A in this vector.
It would be simply written as :

```
Theorem not_empty : forall A n, t A (S n) -> A.
```

but if you tried to prove this using the usual destruct/induction, you end up with two cases:

```
Theorem not_empty : forall A n, t A (S n) -> A.
intros.
destruct X.
- admit. (*here is our impossible clause*)
- exact h.
Admitted.
```

Even though we know the vector has a size equal/higher than one, Coq still gives you a goal that is related when the vector is null. We can abuse from remembering indices and we can catch these cases by hand.

```
Theorem not_empty2 : forall A n, t A (S n) -> A.
intros.
remember (S n).
destruct X.
- inversion Heqn0.
- exact h.
Defined.
```

That is good but would be cooler if there is a tactic that already does it for you and eliminates the impossible clauses?

```
Theorem not_empty3 : forall A n, t A (S n) -> A.
intros.
dependent induction X.
exact h.
Defined.
```

Comment: @blonde04 do you have an example?

Comment: who so? what kind of example do you want to?

Comment: An example where `dependent induction` generates "weird" equalities. (that is self-contained, i.e. works when copied into an empty Coq buffer)

Comment: '''' Dependent induction''' will generate weird equalities whenever they have to generate specific subgoals to avoid the target goals they are trying to avoid.